# react-native app.js index.js

Tags: react-native

I am new to application development with React-native. While creating project with the command `react-native init appname` the `index.js` file is also created inside the project folder. Today, I have learned that there is a better way than installing android emulator to test react-native projects which is Expo. To create  expo projects I need to create react-native project with `create-react-native-app appname` command.  However, the `index.js` file is not created while creating project with this way. Even though, I manually created the `index.js` file, it does not work as it should.

One more question: What is aim of `App.js` and `index.js`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**React Native:** (`react-native init`)

A little bit of history.  In earlier versions of React Native, separate `index.js` files were required for iOS and Android.  `App.js` was meant to contain the top level *cross platform* code for your app.  Then `index.ios.js` and `index.android.js` would import the cross platform code from `App.js` and register/link it with the underlying native modules.  That allowed you to place top-level cross platform code in one file while placing top-level platform specific code in other files. The `index.*.js` files were the connectors that wired up the Javascript to native Android or iOS code.

As React Native evolved to remove the platform specific index files, they kept the paradigm of having the top-level Javascript in `App.js` and using `index.js` to wire that code to the native modules.

***Bottom Line***

As a practical matter, don't touch `index.js`.  Make your top-level modifications in `App.js`.

**Expo:** (`create-react-native-app`)

Expo operates a little differently than baseline React Native. You will notice that an Expo project does not contain the `ios` or `android` directories.  That is because there is no native code associated with an Expo project.  All of the native code is contained in the Expo SDK. Since there is no native code to wire up to your Javascript, you do not need an `index.js` file.

***Bottom Line***

You should not need an `index.js` file in an Expo project.  If your Expo project is not working, there is likely another problem that needs to be resolved.

Comment: this is confusing because most tutorials I've seen as well as GitHub projects either 1) do more work in index.js than app.js (if anything at all) or 2) dont have an App.js file at all

Comment: @Jim, that may be true for pure React Native projects, but the Expo projects I've seen all have an `App.js` without the `index.js`.

Comment: I know it is kinda far from when this answer was posted but I must ask how I can work with some libraries which need index.js files to work such as I18next-react, I'm working on a react native project with expo SDK, and based on how you beautifully explained what is happening what should I do to react the index.js file.

Here is the link to the tutorial: " https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb "

Comment: @navidabasi, the tutorial you linked explains how to install l18next in a React webapp. There will be several modifications required to make the tutorial work in React Native.  For one thing, you will need to detect the mobile device's language settings.  I'm not sure the `index.js` file is affected at all in this case.